# Platform for building quick tools

Tags: programming, calculator

I am looking for a recommendation on a platform for building quick calculation tools (with a gui) that I can reuse and also need basic file functions.

I am an engineer and use a lot of calculations for different equipment sizing exercises and such.  I would like to build a simple software utility that I can store some of the calculations in so that future calculations are quick and easy.
The features that I am most concerned with:

- It should be straightforward to add additional features later.
- I would like the tool to allow packaging so that I can share it with others who are unlikely to participate in development
- I would like file inputs and outputs to be straightforward to implement so that I can just load the calculation parameters if I need to revisit an older calculation.  I would envision the files using xml or something similar.
- The majority of users would be Windows users, so that would be my target platform

I am not a stranger to programming, but have spent most of my time working with C++.  I am looking for some direction if using python, or java or something else  would be the most straightforward for these purposes since I fully understand that you could accomplish these tasks with virtually any language/platform with enough time and work.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a look at the combination of [Python](https://www.python.org/), [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), [Scipy](https://scipy.org/), etc. for the calculations *you may wish to use [cython](http://cython.org/) for any intensive calculations that are not already available* & possibly [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) Notebooks for the UI.

**The calculations part**: Pythons extensive range of libraries give a huge range of functions in a range of fields that are fast and well tested. Python also supports arbitrary precision calculations if needed.

The UI part: There are a number of GUI creation tools available such as [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) but the reasons that I would suggest [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebooks are that:

- Your user interface is a web page
- That web page can contain the code, data, parameters, explanations, formulae, charts and diagrams all in one place
- You can quickly produce reports in PDF format, etc.

**Platforms**: The above tool chains are available for Windows, Linux, Mac, and a large number of other platforms from RaspberryPi up to Super Computer Clusters and your code, *provided you avoid a very few platform specific packages*, will run on **all** of them.

**Packaging**: There are a number of packaging options including:

- Point your users at where to install the tools and let them do so
- PyInstaller, cxFreeze, py2exe, py2App can be user to build packages for specific platforms that include everything needed.
- You could make a server available that is running [JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub) or [DockerSpawner](https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner) that any of your users can connect to an start their own Jupyter session.
- You can bundle up everything needed into a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container.

The best bit about this is that, *with a little care,* you can provide **all** of the above options without having to rebuild your code for each.

**Cost**: All of the above tools are **Free**, gratis & open source.

**Licencing Issues**: All of the above tools are under "permissive" licences which allow commercial use as well as academic and public distribution.

**Quick Development**: Python is very well known for the speed with which it is possible to develop new tools but still allows, by using the libraries, etc., fast execution.